# Connecting an outdoor light to an unfamiliar socket - commercial property

Tags: lighting

I am new to this particular SE site, please feel to edit or comment for clarification.

- New commercial property, outdoor electrical connection to shine lights on trees
- Connection appears to be by a red cable to a box with a circular outlet
- Neighboring property has the same thing
- I'd like to run outdoor lighting either as a string or as a similar spotlight from the similar outlet next to my tree to illuminate my wine bar a bit
- Location is on a sidewalk square in front of a new commercial retail building in Portland, United States

Is there a way to connect standard outdoor lighting to what appears to be the definition of a socket?

Picture 1: my connection, with a bit of plastic over it, as installed by the building.

[image]

Picture 2: this is how a neighboring business did it; I'd like to have either outdoor string lights stem from this or do the same with a light.  I'm not sure if there's a special connection I will need.  Same box as mine, but it maketh light.

[image]

PS - I am entirely amateur.

Comment: Try taking a new photo in daylight and update your post. In the meantime it's unclear what you're asking because your first photo is just a dark blob.

Comment: @ThePhoton - this is what I was expecting (sorry I work nights) I'll try to do the same thing with better light and add it as soon as I can!

Comment: From what little I can see in your first photo, I'd guess that it is just an empty electrical conduit.  If so, you would have to ask the building electrician if you can get an outlet or lamp fixture installed on it.

Comment: @PeterBennett - thanks; I'll try to dig deeper.  I thought maybe this could be an adapter or something I could just collect at a hardware store and save the time.

Comment: Careful.  Commercial outdoor lighting circuits are sometimes 277 volts, and you do not want to shake hands with that stuff.  Talk to your landlord.  Also, can't see well, but it looks like the above pic is the same as the below pic, but with the light fixture snapped off.  The landlord may be able to provision 120V receptacles there for you to plug in Christmas lights or whatever.

Comment: "Improved" photo edit added. As Harper says - it looks identical to the other installation - with light broken off. Should be easy for a professiona but DIT not at all advised. ||Photos: Most phones have LED 'flash'. If not ANY torch will help heaps and brighter better. Steady camera/phone when shooting. Ensure focused.